# Can't open spyder from his .exe (was "changed or moved") but I can from CMD. (happens every time)

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, launching

Does anyone know what can I do to solve this? Every time I try to install spyder (not from anaconda) this happens to me. I uninstall, install it again, then I can use it normally. But after I shutdown my pc and start it again, spyder just dissapear and I have to run it throught my CMD, which works kinda fine? But I'm also getting errors there and also in pycharm so I do think something it's wrong with my python installation lmao.
Example of the error that I'm getting in Pycharm :"pydev debugger: CRITICAL WARNING: This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled (internal generated filenames are not absolute)" So yeah if you know what could I do i'll really appreciate it!!!

thanks in advance and have a nice day/night!

I tried uninstalling spyder and install it again, expecting that their directory or something could be fixed but nope it does the same thing every time. Im guessing it could be the disk where I have it installed but I don't really know because when I'm opening it from CMD, it is from my C (OS) disk so not sure what could be wrong tbh.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.